# Semantic consequence and quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have been self-studying logic and set theory and I'm a bit confused in how to write certain mathematical statements. I think I have grasped somewhat the difference between conditional/material implication, denoted frequently by "$\to$", and semantic consequence, denoted usually by "$\Longrightarrow$" or "$\models$".

My question is the following: in defining what it means for a function $f:A\to B$ to be injective, one could write

$f:A\to B$ is injective $\Longleftrightarrow (\forall x\in A) (\forall y\in A) (f(x) = f(y) \to x=y)$

Now suppose you have a function $g:A\to B$ such that $g$ is injective. Then one would write that for all $x\in A$ and for all $y\in A$,

$g(x) = g(y) \Longrightarrow x=y$.

But it doesn't seem like you could write

$(\forall x\in A)(\forall y\in A) (g(x) = g(y) \Longrightarrow x=y)$

since the above wouldn't be a wff, the symbol "$\Longrightarrow$" not being part of the object language.

To get to the point, how would one make logic statements involving quantifiers and logical relations such as "$\Longrightarrow$" or "$\Longleftrightarrow$"  ? Do you simply not use quantifiers and just write things in plain english such as "for all $x\in A$..." ?

Comment: I think you are confused about $\Longrightarrow$ and $\models$. The symbol $\models$ in logic has a very specialized meaning that is not at all related to any usage of $\Longrightarrow$ I'm familiar with. When speaking about implication in the object language, you always use $\to$. I don't understand why you suddenly switched to $\Longrightarrow$.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, $\to$ and $\implies$ are used rather interchangebly, so don't fret over it too much. Maybe your confusion comes from not having grasped why the truth table for material implication was defined the way it was.

Comment: @DarkRebellion The truth table for material implication can effectively be formally derived from "first principles" using a form of natural deduction. See https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/